# How to implement Search and fillter in telerik tree to search in all level of a Tree

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

This is my javascript.I have a tree which have 4 level.I have to make searching and filtering work first two level of code i.e 0 level and 1 also want when the user will press backspace in the Textbox latest result should be shown..please help me

```
 <telerik:RadPane ID="LeftPanelAssigned" runat="server" Width="20%" CssClass="management" OnClientBeforeResize="LeftPanelAssigned_OnClientBeforeResize">
                  <asp:Label ID="RadTextBox2" Text="Assigned" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="txtAssinedcount" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" />

                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" onkeyup="SearchEmployees(this, '#TreeAssignedWorkflow');"     placeholder="Search employee">
                </asp:TextBox>


                <telerik:RadTreeView ID="TreeAssignedWorkflow" runat="server" CssClass="tree" OnNodeClick="TreeAssignedWorkflow_NodeClick"
                    OnClientMouseOver="TreeAssignedWorkflowOnClientMouseOver" OnClientMouseOut="TreeAssignedWorkflowOnClientMouseOut"
                    OnClientContextMenuItemClicked="WFTreeContextMenuClick">
                    <ContextMenus>
                        <telerik:RadTreeViewContextMenu ID="RadTreeViewContextMenu1" runat="server">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Reference Search">
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Sort By Date">
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                                <telerik:RadMenuItem Text="Sort By Type">
                                </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                            </Items>
                            <CollapseAnimation Type="none" />
                        </telerik:RadTreeViewContextMenu>
                    </ContextMenus>
                </telerik:RadTreeView>
            </telerik:RadPane>
```